# When was each pokemon game made?

Tags: pokemon-series

The first pokemon game I played was Pokémon SoulSilver and I still have it to this day. However, I've always wondered when it was made (Because I had played Platinum before that) If anyone has a list of when each pokemon game was made, please do answer me.

Answer (score 1):

Pokémon SoulSilver was released in Japan in 2009 and was released to the rest of the world in 2010.  Various pages on the Internet contain a list of when each of the Pokémon games were released:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_video_games
- http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_games_by_release_date
- http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_games

Answer (score -4):

It's not complete, it's from memory, and it only includes handheld versions, but here goes:

Red/Blue: 1998
Yellow: 1999
Gold/Silver: 2000
Crystal: I'm pretty sure 2001, but maybe 2002
Ruby/Sapphire: 2003
FireRed/LeafGreen: 2004
Emerald: 2005
Diamond/Pearl: 2007
Platinum: 2009
HearGold/SoulSilver: 2010
Black/White: 2011 (I stopped buying the games after this point, so it might not be 100% accurate)
Black 2/White 2: 2011 or '12
X/Y: 2012
Alpha Sapphire/Omega Ruby: 2014

Comment: X/Y is 2013 and ORAS is 2015

Comment: Yeah... As I said, I was doing it from memory, and I stopped collecting the games after the 5th gen.

Comment: Yeah I know I was just making a correction.

Comment: ORAS was released in november 2014, so KRLW890 is right.